# How to detect iphone on Xubuntu 12.04?

Tags: xubuntu, iphone

I use Xubuntu 12.04 on a MacBook Air 4,1. When I plug in (via usb) an iphone 3gs, it is not recognized. I installed libimobiledevice2 and ifuse, but that did not help. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not see the iPhone directories in the Xubuntu Directory Browser THUNAR. It was possible to see and open the iPhone with Nautilus or with Gigolo.